# Sending NS-3 packets through user-defined socket to another terminal

Tags: c++, c, sockets, ns-3

I wanted to know if anyone has any idea of how I can handle this scenario:

- I want to have two terminals open. In one of them I want to run an NS-3 script file which generates packets and sends it through a socket to the other terminal.
- The other terminal (which is only running a simple C socket program) receives the packet through the socket (and ideally displays the payload or even simpler increases a packet counter).

Any ideas appreciated...

Comment: What's the platform ?

Comment: The platform is debian linux.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can make ns-3 interact with the real world.
Please read this tutorial :
http://www.nsnam.org/wiki/HOWTO_make_ns-3_interact_with_the_real_world

Especially Tap bridge. The Tap Bridge is designed to integrate “real” internet hosts (or more precisely, hosts that support Tun/Tap devices) into ns-3 simulations
http://www.nsnam.org/docs/release/3.18/models/html/tap.html